# firebase where using ISOString but only take date

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs

so i am writing firebase command that take some document if the date in firebase fields is equal with variable that i determine.

And all of date related field in my firebase is always converted `toISOString`,

```
const today = moment().toISOString();

admin.firestore()
     .collection("orders").where("dueDate", "==", today)
     .get()
```

but i then later notice that if i am doing `isEqual` on my where function that only want to take document from specific date then i will not getting it because `toISOString` contain hours, minutes, seconds. like this

```
2020-08-02T19:14:22.104562
```

what if i want to take all document at

```
2020-08-02
```

how do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data you have now:

```
admin.firestore()
    .collection("orders")
    .where("dueDate", ">=", "2020-08-02")
    .where("dueDate", "<", "2020-08-03")
    .get()
```

An alternative (and probably better one, at that) would be to instead store the YYYY-MM-DD string of the date (you can format that with moment as well as shown on their [home page](https://momentjs.com/)), and simply query that for equality:

```
admin.firestore()
    .collection("orders")
    .where("dueDate", "==", "2020-08-02")
    .get()
```